# Sorting a Set of Objects in Python

Tags: python, django, sorting

For my current Twitter Clone project that I am learning Python/Django through, I currently have a set of objects, Tweets, which I would like to sort by pub_date, which is of course the datetime of when they were published. Since sets don't have a sort method (or the convenient order_by that QuerySets have), what would be the best way to sort this set?

Thank you

Comment: Use the `sorted` function

Answer (score 0):

You can produce a `list` of the sorted elements from the `set` via the standard [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) function, with a custom `key` functor to access the correct element to sort by. But you cannot sort the actual elements in a `set`, because `set` in python is by definition unordered.

The heading for the [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) documentation is literally *'Unordered collections of unique elements'*. It's the same reason that `set` doesn't support access by index, because the order of the `set` changes with every element insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to convert that set into a list. with `your_list = list(your_set)`

```
#To sort the list in place... by "pub_date"
your_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.pub_date, reverse=True)

#To return a new list, use the sorted() built-in function...
newlist = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: x.pub_date, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your set to the `sorted` function which will return a sorted list, the sorted function will take a key, you can provide it with a customized function for sorting your items:

```
>>> s = set('abcde')
>>> s
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
>>> sorted(s, key = lambda x: -ord(x))
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```